# Cast object back into it initial form (Model)

Tags: c#, oop, casting, model

I have high and low but still cannot find the solution to my problem so I gonna post it here.

this is my ViewModel

```
    public class CustomerDetail
    {
        FirstName {get;set;}
        LastName {get;set;}
        ID {get;set;}
       Email {get;set;}
    }
```

This is how I pass my model to another method in another folder (project), I am actually passing the model to a reportViewer to export as pdf

```
fileExporter.Initialize(CustomerDetail).Export();
```

FileExportBase

```
 public abstract class FileExportBase
 {
    protected string someotherobject {get;set;}
    protected string someotherobject1 {get;set;}
    protected CustomerDetail customerProfile { get; set; }

    public abstract FileExportBase Initialize(params object[] args);
    public abstract OperationResult Export();

    public class CustomerDetail
    {
       FirstName {get;set;}
       LastName {get;set;}
       ID {get;set;}
       Email {get;set;}
    }

}
```

This is how I retrieve my data

```
public override FileExportBase Initialize(params object[] args)
{
    someotherobject = args[0].ToString();
    someotherobject1 = args[1].ToString();
    //This is where I am facing the problem
    customerProfile = (CustomerDetail)args[2];
    return this;
}
```

So What should I do so I have to cast the object back to the model type that I initially declared it before passing it as object?

Answer (score 0):

In your circumstance, you would more than likely want to do:

```
var customer = new CustomerDetail();
customer = args[2];
```

Now this code has an assortment of problems, for instance you're relying on an index, which may change, thus breaking your code.  You may want to potentially refactor, in a manner that accepts your `CustomerDetail` directly.

```
public class Initialize<T>(T model, params string[] parameters) where T : class, new()
{
     // Do Something
}
```

With the use of generic's, you can now simply do:

```
var customer = new T();
customer = model;
```

This alleviates the risk with the index, while being flexible.  Then with a small bit of reflection you can easily ascertain the Properties and Field Index's within your `T`.

Not sure if this helps you, but based on what I see and understand of your problem this may be valid food for thought.  If you add some more clarification, I may be able to better assist.

Comment: I have tried with 
"var customer = new CustomerDetail();
customer = args[2];" and is not working that's why I post the question here.
The error message for this is "cannot implicitly convert type "object" to 'FileExport.FileExportBase.CostumerDetail'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What I am thinking is that should I bring the viewModel to higher level so both project uses the same model or I should pass the data as string and deserializing it back to model while receiving it at Initialize

Comment: I was under the notion the domain class, was a reference or within same project. Thus both have access.